# Target all links within div — Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to target links within a certain div. I understand how to target all the links, like so:

```
var colors = [ 'BlueViolet', 'CadetBlue', 'Coral', 'Crimson', 'DarkGoldenRod', 'DarkOliveGreen'],
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var elem = a[i],
        color = colors[0];
    elem.style.color = color;
    colors.push(color);
    colors.shift();
}
```

Obviously, it's targeting all links: http://lexicantest.tumblr.com/

Is there a way for me to target all the links within a certain id/class?

Comment: Is it acceptable to use jquery?

Comment: If it's possible to translate the loop I've used above, then it would be preferable :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For ID:

```
var a = document.getElementById('divYouwant').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var elem = a[i],
        color = colors[0];
    elem.style.color = color;
    colors.push(color);
    colors.shift();
}
```

If you want to grab it from a class, you would have to grab each class and then grab each set of anchor tags...

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        var elem = a[j],
            color = colors[0];
        elem.style.color = color;
        colors.push(color);
        colors.shift();
    }
}
```

Basically you follow the same concept as just getting all the links. The only difference is you don't use the document as the reference. First you grab the div that you want, and then from there, grab an array of all the anchor tags.

Comment: Just for clarity, this requires that you give the div element and id attribute to be able to reference it.

Comment: In the question: `links within a certain id/class`