# Get nested element by tag->id->element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElement(div#menuArea).getElements(a)
```

I want to get all the a elements from a `div` with id `"menuArea"`. I think above syntax is wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should research for answers before asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765639/target-all-links-within-div-javascript#answer-15765664

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('menuArea').getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Or for IE8+

```
document.querySelectorAll('#menuArea a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try jQuery:

```
$('#'menuArea a');
```

About class,  try this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('menuArea').getElementsByTagName('a')
d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
```

This is pure JavaScript.

Comment: I need to use only JS. Thanks