# Jekyll unhide reference-style links on Github pages

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I have been using github pages with `jekyll` for auto-generating my blog using `markdown` documents.

I would like to use reference-style links then show a list of the links at the bottom of the page.

basically, I want the reference-style links to be printed on the page, by default they are hidden.

The idea is to have a list of references that a reader can refer to for more information.

for example, the following text:

```
# some header
...some body text in the blog with a link to [wikipedia][1]
...
...
# reference links
[1]: https://www.wikipedia.org
```

*should* generate the following output:

---

## some header

...some body text in the blog with a link to [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org)
...
...

## reference links

[1]: https://www.wikipedia.org

---

As seen, the reference-style link is used in the `markdown` but it is also displayed on the page.

The previous "correct" output was achieved by duplicating each line and escaping the special characters, but this seems a bit redundant.

Can this be achieved by changes to `_config.yml` or using `ruby`? Other options are also welcome (`css` magic?).

tldr; I want a way to "unhide" the reference-style links at the bottom of my `markdown` page.

Comment: Jekyll and unHyde :) I think you have to use CSS to override and display them `display:block`

Comment: i'm not sure i follow. looking at the html, there doesn't seem to be anything there to show, is there a way to generate them at the end of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to understand exactly what is doing what:

- Your markdown parser is converting your markdown into html.
- Jekyll is taking that html and organizing it into pages.
- GitHub pages is serving up those html pages.
- The client reads that html and executes any JavaScript, etc.

The problem is that the markdown parser doesn't include the reference links at the bottom of the page. It's not like they're there but hidden. They simply aren't there. So you aren't going to find a CSS solution, because there isn't anything to style. You **might** be able to accomplish this with a custom markdown parser that includes the reference links in the generated html, but that won't work with GitHub pages and is probably going to be pretty hackish.

Another option is to execute JavaScript that uses `document.links` to get every link on the page, then output them in a `<ul>` or something at the bottom of the page. Something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links):

```
var links = document.links;
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var linkHref = document.createTextNode(links[i].href);
  var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
  document.body.appendChild(linkHref);
  document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
}
```

You might restrict that to only include links in a certain div (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765639/target-all-links-within-div-javascript)), that way you don't have to parse out your navigation links and whatnot. You also have to consider the order.

Another option might be to include them in each post's frontmatter as a yml list, then show those in the layout that displays the post.

Of course, you could also simply create the reference yourself using markdown.

Comment: `It's not like they're there but hidden. They simply aren't there. ` I did notice this in the HTML, and started poking around more. I will have to make a custom parser most likely. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy No problem. Note that a custom markdown engine will not work with GitHub Pages. It also sounds like a pain in the neck to develop, but maybe you're more comfortable with writing markdown engines than I am. If I were you I would try the JavaScript option first, then the frontmatter option if that doesn't work, and if neither of those worked I'd probably just write the references myself. But in any case, I wish you luck!